# Media Queries for Phones

Tags: html, css

I'm using media queries in my css:

```
/* Tablet */
@media (max-width: 979px){
 }
/* Phone */
@media (max-width: 767px){
}
```

When I drag my browser really small on my desktop computer it switches to the phone layout, is there a way to prevent this so the small size is only seen on the phone?

Comment: Try `max-device-width` instead

Comment: Why would you want this? If the browser window is really narrow, surely the "desktop" design wouldn't fit, otherwise there wouldn't be any point in having a "phone" design. Stop thinking about "phone" and "desktop" and focus on "narrow" and "wide".

Comment: Are you sure that's the behaviour you want? Because a device with 767px of screen width isn't really a small screen device... Also, try `@media only screen and (max-device-width: 767px)`

Comment: Media queries are used for Responsive Layouts, not for phone specific layouts, but responsive layouts are useful for phones too. And responsive layouts are great for tablets, widgets and other things. So I would recommend to use them. Maybe you can use more media query steps for a better behavior, if you change your browser size (e.g. <480, 480-768, 768-960, 960<)

Comment: http://designshack.net/articles/css/responsive-design-why-youre-doing-it-wrong/

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really a need to do this.  This is the point of responsive, it's device-agnostic.  So if a user comes to your site on desktop but their browser is really skinny the content will fit it (such as the Windows 8 Metro IE10 sidebar thing).  You don't want to limit it only to phones, once you've done that you're going down a road that isn't meant to be traveled with responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, but the question is you really think the overkill need for it will be valid?

You can add a class to the HTML tag for phone devices (using JavaScript or any other method to verify if its a phone or not) and use this class inside the `@media` so only when this class is applied the media queries will take effect, small example:

HTML:

```
<html class="phone-device">

</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Phone */
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .phone-device{

    }
}
```

But again this is not the right thing to do...